# Sonarqube API response with date-time in parameters

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops, sonarqube-web

Trying to extract issues and getting this error while hitting SonarQube API:

```
api/issues/search?createdAfter=2013-05-01T13:00:00+0100
```

> {"errors":[{"msg":"Date '2018-06-05 14:00:00 1000' cannot be parsed as either a date or date+time"}]}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to encode the '+' to be url friendly, so you need to replace if with `%2B`.
See this page for more information : 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp